# Print multiple texts from multiple elements with same class name

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Im trying to print all the product names from an e commerce website in selenium using java but its printing only the first name of the product from the first class it finds. How to print all the product names from all the classes with same class name?

This is my code:

```
package introduction;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Getproductnames {

    private static int i;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Temp/chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        driver.get("https://www.fipola.in/chicken");
        driver.findElement(By.id("DelLocation")).sendKeys("600020");
        driver.findElement(By.className("top_pincode_select")).click();

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        List<WebElement> products=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.product-item-link"));

        for(int i=0; i<products.size(); i++);
        {
            String[] names = new String[]{products.get(i).getText()};
            System.out.println(names[i] + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to print all the products name

```
List<WebElement> products=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.product-item-link"));


for(int i =0;i<products.size();i++) {
 String elementText = products.get(i).getText(); 
 System.out.println(elementText); 
}
```